# Loop making a huge difference in performance measurement

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

I'm trying to create Poolable objects, or in other words, objects that are recycled instead of creating new ones from scratch, which is way too slow.

```
var Poolable = {
  pool: [],

  new: function(args) {
    var obj;
    if (this.pool.length > 0) {
      obj = this.pool.shift();
      obj._recycled = false;
    } else {
      obj = Object.create(this.prototype);
    }

    this.apply(obj, arguments);
    return obj;
  },

  delete: function(obj) {
    if (obj._recycled) {
      throw ("This object has already been recycled!");
    }
    obj._recycled = true;
    this.pool.push(obj);
  }
};

var extend = function(a, b) {
  for (var i in b) {
    if (b[i]) {
      a[i] = b[i];
    }
  }

  return a;
};

var Vector = extend(function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}, Poolable);

Vector.prototype.add = function(v) {
  this.x += v.x;
  this.y += v.y;
};
```

I can use this like so:

```
var v = Vector.new(1, 2);
// When I'm done
Vector.delete(v);
```

I was testing this to see if there's any noticeable improvement, but then the weird thing happened: using the Poolable version is much faster inside a big for loop, whereas Non-Poolable ones are much faster on small for loops.

Small loop:
http://jsperf.com/poolable-vs-non-poolable-objects/8

Big loop:
http://jsperf.com/poolable-vs-non-poolable-objects/9

Question: Where did I mess up setting up the test?

Comment: Is this code for browser? In that case why do you need to use a pool?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes. I'm trying to make a 2D Physics Engine and the high number of Vectors being created was slowing the thing down quite a lot.

Comment: Any reasons why you can't use stateless objects?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I don't know what you mean by that. The point of having vectors is to save data (x, y coord), which requires state. What alternative are you suggesting?

Comment: what are vectors being used for?

Comment: @gurvinder372 A lot of things: handling position, velocity, acceleration, forces...

Comment: Can you give an example? I can give you an approach then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107329/discussion-between-slysherz-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting poolable benchmark slower than non-pool for both test... am I missing something?

In the non-pool test you are not deleting the objects, so maybe they get deleted when the test finishes which led to a better perf. Also I would think that the extra logic introduced by poolable version has a performance cost for small loops but starts to be more efficient than a non-pool on larger dataset, which is probably what you are looking for?

For such a simple structure, did you try to replace the whole Object.create + extend by just:

```
obj = { x: x, y: y }
```

Comment: On my machine, Poolable objects are twice as fast in the big loop, using firefox. Also you missed the "add" function, which on the real Vectors is not just 1, but a bunch of them: add, sub, mult, cross...